# Can I interrupt a method while this method is working?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, interrupt, terminate

Can we interrupt a method while its working?Because I have a method that in a thread and I have to interrupt that method when button click. How can I do that?

I tried Abort() method but its not working. Because Abort() is a method which don't have any garanty behavior. I mean if we use that method, we don't sure about method termination.

I have just a method name like DoSomething() because I use a DLL which is written in C++. Hence I dont have a source code of method. And if I click a button, this method must be terminated

Please give me some advice about it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Post some code: Hard to determine how your thread is working.. Because there are so less possibilities how it is implemented

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping a Thread, ManualResetEvent, volatile boolean or cancellationToken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476528/stopping-a-thread-manualresetevent-volatile-boolean-or-cancellationtoken)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the method implement a flag to abort it and code your way around the problem. This is a conceptual pseudo-C# example of what I'd do:

```
private bool aborted = false;

public ResultClass Method()
{
    for (i = 0; i < int.MaxValue && !aborted; i++)
    {
      // ...
    }

    if (aborted)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new ResultClass(...);
}

public void Abort()
{
    aborted = true;
}
```

This might look like a lot of code but it is cleaner, you can clean-up and handle stuff as you need it. Aborting a thread, instead, is a messy affair and can only happen when the thread hits a `WaitSleepJoin` state.

If you really need to abort, **at least** do something like this:

```
try {
    // abortable code
}
finally
{
    // clean-up resources
}
```

Comment: if I use this code, I cannot escape to out of method. This method just usable instead of Abort() method. Am I right?

Comment: I have just a method name like DoSomething(). And if I click a button, this method must be terminated

Comment: Better to use a `ManualResetEvent` or some such to do this, or an `Interlocked.Exchange/Interlocked.Read`

Comment: Yes, it may be better but really performance and readability/maintainability has to be taken into account when multithreading is involved, so as simple or complex a solution it totally depends on many factors how to best solve such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Abort on a thread and not on a method. If you want to interrupt a method use return.

Comment: `return` can be used inside the method. How can you do it from outside the method?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. If someone has problem like that, maybe it can find an answer in following pages

I got some information about my question in below link

[Abort call to unmanaged DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781484/abort-call-to-unmanaged-dll)

I found an example about my solving way

[Using kernel32 CreateThread/TerminateThread inside Azure Worker Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043408/using-kernel32-createthread-terminatethread-inside-azure-worker-role)

And you can use this page. This page contains a lot of code part about PInvoke.

http://www.pinvoke.net/